# Building an incorrect json through controller function

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm building a JSON from some web conntent, but when I try to validate it through:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I get

- Extra closing }
- Multiple root elements

This is the result json I get (yes, I know it's built from the same 5 car models, but that's another point)

https://pastebin.com/sfXTp18n

This is par of code of my Laravel controller which is generating this JSON (it's awful but it's the only way I could think of):

```
public function iterateDynamicJson($json){

$result = '['; //open json 

foreach ($json->makes as $trademark){

    //foreach trademark

        if($trademark->Group!=""){ //deletes trademark duplicates
            $result.='{"id":'.$trademark->Id.',"name": "'.$trademark->MakeName.'",'.'"modelItems"'.': ['; 
        }

    foreach ($json->models as $id => $name){

        //foreach model

        $this->inc+=1; //number of models? I need to break 

        //break when trademark changes => related to inc

        if($name=="Other "){ //
            break;
        }

        $result.='{"id":'.$id.',"name":"'.$name.'"},'; 
    }

    $result=$this->extractString($result,0,-1); //removes last comma from models iteration 
    $result.= ']},'; //shuts models array and closes trademark
}

$result=$this->extractString($result,0,-1); //removes last comma from trademarks 
$result.= ']'; //closes json 

return $result;

}
```

Any idea? I don't really know how to correct this JSON, I still think everything is correct in this flow, but it's not. Thanks in advance

Comment: Idea: Why do you create JSON by yourself? One suggestion is to use array() and use json_encode function. An efficient way to convert an array to JSON format.

Comment: 100% with @RutvijKothari use `json_encode`. I find the `var_export` function is extremely useful when tinkering with json-encoding.

Comment: Because I'm merging two existing roots of a JSON I collect, and I need that exact structure (trademark=>id,name,array of models=>id, name) but I will try with array() and json_encode, will let you know